# How to limit this modsecurity rule to one file?

Tags: mod-security, mod-security2

I have this rule bellow, and I'd like to limit for only wp-login.php files. Is it possible?

SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent "@contains python-requests" "id:1000000,t:none,t:lowercase,deny,nolog,msg:'BAD BOT - Detected and Blocked. '"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [chained rules](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-%28v2.x%29#chain):

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "wp-admin.php" "chain,id:1000000,t:none,t:lowercase,deny,nolog,msg:'BAD BOT - Detected and Blocked. '"
    SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent "@contains python-requests" ",t:none,t:lowercase"
```